# Is it a good practice to use Realm with try-with-resources?

Tags: java, realm, try-with-resources

In many places there are recommendations to call `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` in `onCreate` method of the `Activity` and call `close` on Realm instance in `onDestroy` (or in corresponding methods of presenter).

However, for me it would be cleaner to use Java's try-with-resources construct:

```
try (final Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
  // do stuff 
}
```

Why cleaner? IMO it is easier to manage that narrow scope of `realm` instance. Getting the instance in one moment of lifecycle and closing it in the another one, reminds me of old days with C++, when we had to worry about calling `delete` in right moment.

The question is: **is it a bad practice to use Realm in such way?** Why none of tutorials mention it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is it a bad practice to use Realm in such way?

No, this is recommended for **background threads**.

See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realm-instances in the official docs.

---

For UI thread, the `onCreate()`/`onDestroy()` is recommended, because if you close the local Realm instance, then the results that are bound to it become invalidated. A Realm needs to be open in order to provide the connection to the results in the Realm file.